# Testing Pixijs in Vitest

Tags: pixi.js, vitest

I want to unit-test Code that creates a Pixi-JS application with Vitest, however I get a "Worker not defined"-Error.

Other code stripped away, this is what I tried (in a vite-project):

```
/**
 * @vitest-environment jsdom
 */

import { Application } from '@pixi/node';
import { describe, it } from 'vitest';

describe('Render', function() {
  it('should be able to create a Render instance', async function() {
    new Application();
  });
});
```

Running `npm run test` gave me that the test failed:

```
 FAIL  test/render/Render.test.ts [ test/render/Render.test.ts ]
ReferenceError: Worker is not defined
 ❯ node_modules/@pixi/assets/lib/_virtual/checkImageBitmap.worker.mjs:20:30
 ❯ test/render/Render.test.ts:1:31
      1| /**
      2|  * @vitest-environment jsdom
       |                          ^
      3|  */
      4|

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯[1/1]⎯

 Test Files  1 failed (1)
      Tests  no tests
   Start at  20:18:55
   Duration  0ms
```

Comment: This seems to be a known issue in the pixi Github repository. https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/10170 ... Try using a different version than 7.4.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did find that Issue but didn't follow what the conversation meant. Using pixi.js Version 8.0.1 fixed it for me

Comment: It still won't work to init the pixi.js app. I get a different Error now uff

Comment: Unless you have specific needs, you can temporarily roll back to ~7.3.0.

Comment: I tried. I get the same Error in all 7.x.x Versions